# Run multiple request from Action and wait till one ends

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api

I have web api 2.1 service. Here is my Action :

```
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            // Desired functionality :
            // make e.g 5 request to `CheckSomething` with different parameter asynchronously/parallel  and if any of them returns status Ok end request and return its result as result of `Get` action;

        }

    public IHttpActionResult CheckSomething(int id)
    {
        // some code
        if(!something)
           return NotFound();
        return Ok(id);
    }
```

What is best way to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: [WaitAny](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270672(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your tasks in an array and then call [Task.WaitAny](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270672(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var finishedTask = Task.WaitAny(myTasks);
```

When it's finished `finishedTask` will be the index of the task in `myTasks` array that finished. You should then be able to get the result from it.

```
var result = myTasks[finishedTask].Result;
```

Actually, since you want to wait for the first to return `Ok`, I'd do something like this:

```
var taskList = new List<Task>() { ...your tasks ... };
while (taskList.Count > 0) 
{
    var idx = Task.WaitAny(taskList.ToArray());
    if (taskList[idx].Result is Ok)   // whatever the appropriate check is?
    {
        return taskList[idx].Result;
    }
    taskList.RemoveAt(idx);
}
// If you got here, none of your tasks returned ok
// so handle that however you want
```

Comment: What if the first result isn't successful?

Comment: @Servy: I already edited the answer to handle that. I'd just keep running `WaitAll` (removing the already finished task first, of course) until you get one that returns successfully or until you run out of tasks.

Answer (score -2):

I would use

> Task.WhenAll

l to ensure that all task complete before continiuning.

here is an example:

```
var tasks = new Task[]
            {
                task1,
                task2
            };
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
var task1Result = ((Task<Task1Result>)tasks[0]).Result;
var task2Result = ((Task<Task2Result>)tasks[1]).Result;
```

if all the task return the same result you don't need to cast, but you can also run task that return different result type in parallel for which you will need to cast back.

Comment: He wants to get the *first successful result*, not wait for all of the results.